# possible to alter my tooltip plugin to accept "click" option without too much trouble?

Tags: javascript

I have a plugin I've written for the purpose of showing/hiding tooltips. It works to the point that I'm happy enough to use it in production work, in the case when all I need is for it to show/hide the tooltip on hover. However I'd like to now alter it to show/hide on click as well.

I can get it to work up to a point but depending on what I try it either doesn't do one of the following: when I click from one tooltip activating element to another the previous tooltip doesn't hide - or - when I click from one element to another the previous tooltip closes but the next tooltip doesn't immediately open as well.

I've tried `e.target !== e.currentTarget` within an `if` statement and a number of other things that didn't quite work. My suspicion is that the plugin as it stands is not going to be easily extensible without more than a few simple conditionals, but if anyone can have a look and let me know if possible and if so hopefully offer me some direction or suggestions on how I might go about amending it it would be much appreciated.

If anyone is wondering why I am trying to reinvent the wheel (when there are so many tooltip plugins out there): it's mainly a learning exercise. I'd love to get better at writing reusable code. I'd also like a viable tooltip plugin that suits my needs in regards to being something very lightweight and framework independent, which in my searching I wasn't able to find.

Below is the code as it stands, in one of the two before mentioned states:

```
(window => {
    let template = document.createElement('div'),
        pos = {x: 0, y: 0},
        targetPos,
        tip,
        tipWidth,
        tipHeight,
        innerOffsetX,
        delay;

    template.inner = document.createElement('div');
    template.inner.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip-inner');
    template.appendChild(template.inner);

    /**
     * @param {string|HTMLElement} container Either a selector string or the element.
     * @param {Object=} config Optional argument for overriding the default configuration.
     */
    class Tooltip {
        constructor(container, config) {
            this.offsetX = 0;
            this.offsetY = 0;
            this.position = 'top';
            this.margin = 6;
            this.offsetBubble = 0;
            this.delayShow = this.delayHide = 0;
            this.clickToShow = false;
            this.tooltipInClass = 'tooltip-in';
            this.tooltip = null;
            this.toggle = true;

            if (typeof container === 'string') {
                this.container = document.querySelector(container);
            } else {
                this.container = container;
            }

            if (config) {
                for (let p in config) {
                    if (typeof config[p] === 'object') {
                        this.delayShow = config.delay.show;
                        this.delayHide = config.delay.hide;
                    } else {
                        this[p] = config[p];
                    }
                }
            }

            template.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip ' + this.position);
        }

        show() {
            return e => {
                if (e.target.hasAttribute('data-tooltip')) {

                    if (this.toggle === true) {

                        targetPos = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

                        pos.x = targetPos.left + e.target.offsetWidth / 2 + this.offsetX;
                        pos.y = targetPos[this.position] + this.offsetY + document.body.scrollTop;

                        template.inner.innerText = e.target.getAttribute('data-tooltip');

                        this.tooltip = document.body.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));

                        tip = this.tooltip;

                        tipWidth = tip.clientWidth;
                        tipHeight = tip.clientHeight;

                        pos.x -= tipWidth / 2;
                        pos.y -= this.position === 'bottom' ? -8 : tipHeight;

                        // Nudge tooltip content into the window area if needed
                        if (pos.x + tipWidth > tip.offsetParent.clientWidth) {
                            innerOffsetX = pos.x + tipWidth - tip.offsetParent.clientWidth + 6;
                            tip.firstChild.setAttribute('style', `left:-${innerOffsetX}px`);
                        } else if (pos.x < 0) {
                            innerOffsetX = -pos.x + 6;
                            tip.firstChild.setAttribute('style', `left:${innerOffsetX}px`);
                        }

                        // Reposition tooltip below/above target and flip arrow if needed
                        if (pos.y < 0 && this.position !== 'bottom') {
                            pos.y += tipHeight * 2;
                            tip.classList.remove(this.position);
                            tip.classList.add('bottom');
                        } else if (pos.y + tipHeight > tip.offsetParent.scrollHeight && self.position !== 'top') {
                            tip.classList.remove(this.position);
                            tip.classList.add('top');
                        }

                        tip.setAttribute('style', `left:${Math.floor(pos.x)}px;top:${Math.floor(pos.y)}px`);

                        if (this.delayShow !== 0) {

                            // Don't delay showing the tooltip if entering an adjacent item with a "tooltip" data attribute.
                            if (e.relatedTarget.hasAttribute('data-tooltip')) {
                                delay = 0;
                            } else {
                                delay = this.delayShow;
                            }

                            if (typeof this.timeoutid === 'number') {
                                clearTimeout(this.timeoutid);
                                delete this.timeoutid;
                            }

                            this.timeoutid = setTimeout(function () {
                                tip.classList.add(this.tooltipInClass);
                                this.toggle = false;
                            }, delay);

                        } else {
                            tip.classList.add(this.tooltipInClass);
                            this.toggle = false;
                        }

                    } else {
                        this.hide('hide');
                        this.toggle = true;
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        hide(e) {
            if (e.target && e.target.hasAttribute('data-tooltip') || typeof e === 'string') {
                document.body.lastChild.classList.remove(this.tooltipInClass);
                document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild);
            }
        }

        init() {
            if (!this.clickToShow) {
                this.container.addEventListener('mouseover', this.show());
                this.container.addEventListener('mouseout', this.hide);
            } else {
                this.container.addEventListener('click', this.show());
            } 
        }
    }

    window.Tooltip = window.Tooltip || Tooltip;

})(window);

// Usage examples
const elem = document.querySelector('.container'),
    tooltip = new Tooltip(elem, {
        offsetX: -2,
        delay: {show: 0, hide: 0},
        clickToShow: true
    }).init();
```

And a jsfiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/et9hLnkt/**

Again, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a little your plugin, I added two thing to handle the problem:

I added this if to control if the link you clicked is the same target if some tooltip is already opened:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-in")[0] &&
  e.target !== document.getElementsByClassName("current-target-tooltip")[0]) {
  this.hide('hide');
  this.toggle = true;
  document.getElementsByClassName("current-target-tooltip")[0].classList.remove("current-target-tooltip");
}
```

then I just added the add/remove class on the current target in if/else:

```
    if (this.toggle === true) {
      e.target.classList.add('current-target-tooltip');
      ...
    } else {
      e.target.classList.remove('current-target-tooltip');
      this.hide('hide');
      this.toggle = true;
   }
```

and here is your updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/et9hLnkt/18/